# Dota 2 corrupted download file apk01_46.vpk

Tags: steam, dota-2

The newly released dota patch 7.00 caused me some trouble. Every time I exit steam It resets my download.

After multiple attempts I managed to finish the download however every time I try to open the game an error message states that I have a corrupted File.

> steamapps/downloading/570/dota/apk01_46.vpk

I tried deleting the file and verifying the game files twice but it still says that apk01_46.vpk is corrupted.

I already tried reinstalling the game three times and now the previous error message says that the error is vcredist_x86.

Can I solve this problem without having to re-download the entire game?

Comment: wonder if going to that folder and deleting the corrupted vpk would force it to redownload.

Answer (score 1):

I have got the same problem with CS:GO and I had to delete the whole game. If you got problems with vcredist_x86, try downloading it from the  [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=5555) page.

If you still got the problem try finding working files and insert them instead of yours. Or try to relog on another account and try it playing from this account.

(If you want to find successful files try to download game on another computer) and delete file Downloading 570 (or something like that).

Answer (score -4):

I deleted the folder `\Steam\steamapps\downloading` several times and download it (6 time). It worked